# Concatenating audio always leads to damage in quality

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

I'm trying to combine a long list of audio clips from Amazon Polly using python. Originally I used ffmpeg and os.

```
st= 'ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i sound1.mp3- i sound2.mp3 -i sound3.mp3 -i sound4.mp3 -filter_complex [0:0] [0:1] [0:2] [0:3] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out] -map [out] output.mp3'
os.sys(st)
```

While this works, the audio comes out with a sharp ring/hiss in the back, and the audio ends up skipping around and breaking, even if the original clips sound just fine on their own. I tried changing the max and min hz of the clip, but it doesn't fix the ringing, mismatched audio, and makes the audio sound fuzzy. So I tried using pydub, because I read it didn't damage audio:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio_list=[sound1.mp3, sound2.mp3, sound3.mp3, sound4.mp3]
playlist_songs = [AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file) for mp3_file in audio_list]
combined = AudioSegment.empty()
combined = playlist_songs[0]

for song in playlist_songs:
   combined += song

combined.export("/path/to/file/PYDUB_output.mp3", format="mp3")
```

And my audio still comes out with bad sound! Any suggestions on ways I can improve audio quality when combining clips while using ffmpeg or pydub/better programs that won't leave  my sound damaged when concatenating? I can't find any useful advice online for this issue.

Comment: For proper concatenation each input must have the same attributes. Copy and paste the complete output of `ffmpeg -i sound1.mp3 -i sound2.mp3 -i sound3.mp3 -i sound4.mp3` to show info about each input.

Comment: Any update on the issue @Glitchin?